# Getting autohotkey to work with Opera

Tags: autohotkey, opera

I want to use the following line in an autohotkey script:

```
#IfWinActive, Opera
```

But it doesn't work with the newest version of Opera.  I don't think that it has a window name.  So how can I get it to work with Opera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Window Spy I get these results: (right click the AHK icon in the tray, then click on the Opera window)

```
>>>>>>>>>>( Window Title & Class )<<<<<<<<<<<
Getting autohotkey to work with Opera - Super User - Opera
ahk_class OpWindow
```

So use this in your AHK script:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class OpWindow
```

(I am using Opera 10.51 build 3315; AHK 1.0.48.05)

Answer (score 0):

Use the AU3_Spy.exe program that came with AutoHotkey to find out the class name of the Opera window. Then you can use `#IfWinActive ahk_class classname`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest autohotkey you can use:

```
#IfWinActive,Ahk_exe Opera.exe
```